# When do you really need async on a web framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, nancy

Async has become a buzzword in .net and MS have introduced it in Web API 2 so that more requests can be handled whilst others are waiting on IO to finish.

Whilst I can see the benefit of this, is it really a concern? A x64 architecture has 30000+ threads in the Thread Pool so unless you have that many concurrent users on your website is async really required? Even if you have that many concurrent users without caching I'm pretty sure SQL Server will fall over with that many requests?

Apart from it being shiny when is there a real need to have async routing on a web framework?

Comment: I'm thinking you've gotten the thread pool and the request queue limit mixed up. By default, ASP.net 4.0 only allocates a maximum of 20 worker threads and 20 IO threads per CPU core with a maximum of 100 for both. These are configured using the [`processModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7w2sway1(v=vs.100).aspx) element in the web.config file. If you think about it 30,000 threads with a 256KB stack each would require ~7.3GiB just for the thread stacks alone - not counting other any process memory. For what it's worth, the default `requestQueueLimit` is 5,000.

Comment: So it only allows 100 per core, so 400 concurrent users on a quad core and uses requestQueueLimit to queue up incoming requests. Does IIS not help in this area to allow larger number of requests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many of the other answers here are coming from a UI (desktop/mobile app) perspective, not a web server perspective.

> Async has become a buzzword in .net and MS have introduced it in Web API 2 so that more requests can be handled whilst others are waiting on IO to finish.

`async` and `await` were introduced in .NET 4.5 / VS 2012. However, ASP.NET has had asynchronous request capability since .NET 2.0 - a very long time ago. And there have been people using it.

What `async` and `await` bring to the table is asynchronous code *that is easy to maintain*.

> Whilst I can see the benefit of this, is it really a concern?

The key benefit of `async` on the server is scalability. Simply put, `async` tasks scale far better than threads.

@Joshua's comment is key regarding the memory; a thread takes a significant amount of memory (and don't forget the kernel-mode stack which cannot be paged out), while an `async` request literally only takes a few hundred bytes.

There's also bursting to consider. The .NET threadpool has a limited injection rate, so unless you set your `minWorkerThread` count to a value much higher than you normally need, then when you get a burst of traffic some requests will 503 before .NET can spin up enough threads to handle them. `async` keeps your threads free (as much as possible) so it handles bursting traffic better.

> A x64 architecture has 30000+ threads in the Thread Pool so unless you have that many concurrent users on your website is async really required?

@Joshua is again correct when he points out that you're probably thinking of a request queue limit (which defaults to 1000 for the IIS queue and 5000 for the ASP.NET request limit). It's important to note that once this queue is filled (during bursty traffic), new requests are rejected with 503.

> Even if you have that many concurrent users without caching I'm pretty sure SQL Server will fall over with that many requests?

Ah, now *that's* another question entirely.

I'm giving a [talk at ThatConference 2013](http://www.thatconference.com/sessions/session_630) specifically on `async` servers. One part of that talk is situations where `async` doesn't help ([my Twitter update](https://twitter.com/aSteveCleary/status/362388167761993728)).

There's an [excellent blog post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous.aspx) that takes the position that asynchronous db calls are just not worth the effort. It's important to note the assumptions in this post:

1. At the time that post was written, asynchronous web servers were difficult. These days we have `async` and more and more libraries are offering asynchronous APIs (e.g., Entity Framework).
2. The architecture assumes a single web server with a single SQL Server backend. This was a very common setup traditionally, but is quickly changing today.

Where `async` servers really shine is when your backend can also scale. E.g., a web service, Azure SQL, NoSQL cluster, etc. Example: I'm writing an MVC/WebAPI server that uses Azure SQL and Storage for its backend (for all practical purposes, I can act like they have infinite scalability); in that case, I'm going to make my server `async`. In situations like this, you can scale your server 10x or more by using `async`.

But if you just have a single SQL Server backend (and have no plans to change to Azure SQL), then there's no point in making your web server `async` because you're limited by your backend anyway.

Comment: ASP.NET has had asynchronous request capability since .NET 1.0 for HTTP handlers. In 2.0 na API for WebForms async page task was introduced (and async HTTP modules, I think).

Answer (score 4):

1. When long operations can be efficiently executed in parallel. For instance, you have to execute two SQLs and load three pictures - do all five operations as async and await them all. In this case the overall time will be the longest duration of five operations, but not *the sum of the durations*.
2. Pre-fetch. If you can predict (with good probability) what user will do (e.g. almost certainly, (s)he will want to see the details...) you may start preparing the next page (frame, window) while user's reading the previous.

Comment: I don't think prefetching is a good use case for `async` on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

where did you get  30000 from. i dont remember exactly but  I think Asp.net uses 12 x number of cores threads.

Comment: So how does IIS come into play because pretty sure that can handle more than 12,24,36,48 requests

Comment: if request takes 1 second to handle then Asp.net will only handle 12 requests per second per one core. And it will take some time to start 12 threads per CPU. Asp.net won't add more then 2 threads per second.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use async, when operation take too long time (upload, export, processing) and user have to know about progress.

Comment: `async` cannot be used to report progress to the user from an ASP.NET request.

Comment: Looks like i have a mistake with concept, because i thought we talk about asynchronous requests and not only `async` statement.

Answer (score -2):

You need async in following scenarios

1) When you are performing a very long operation and you don't want to freeze your UI.

2) When you designed some task that needs to be completed in background.

For example, You are rendering images from database. But you don't want your page to be freeze at that time async is really helpful.